# Why is my social policy cost so high?

Tags: civilization-5

So I am brand new to Civ 5 and the Civ games in general. I've watched a couple tutorials on youtube and that's about it. I started playing the "walk me through it" tutorial and I realized that my social policy cost is at 4995 but from the videos I've seen, it usually starts around 100.

[image]

What can I do to lower the cost to adopt a social policy?

Comment: Is that during the tutorial?

Comment: @TimS. Yes it is

Comment: Check it on a regular game. I suspect they do that because they don't want you to be able to upgrade policies during the tutorial.

Comment: @TimS. Ah yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are playing the tutorial. You'll find that saving the game is also disabled. I just started a regular game, and the "Next Policy Cost" is 15 culture:[image]

I'm sure a regular game will have more reasonable culture costs for policies.